# Bootstrap 5: dropdown menu icon doesn't show properly

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I'm using Angular 14 with Bootstrap 5. I have the following code, just the **basic Bootstrap dropdown menu**:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my `index.html` file I have the following imports. I'm using a Bootstrap theme, so I have the imports related with it.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/libs.bundle.css" />
<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/theme.bundle.css" />

<!-- JAVASCRIPT -->

<!-- Vendor JS -->
<script src="/assets/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- Theme JS -->
<script src="/assets/js/theme.bundle.js"></script>
```

I'm facing an issue where the dropdown menu icon doesn't show and I don't know why. The dropdown works well with collapse but the icon looks like this:

[image: Dropdown menu icon]

I think it can be related with a class named `.dropdown-toggle:after` which has the following code. The font might not be rendering correctly.

```css
.dropdown-toggle:after {
  border: none!important;
  content: "\e92e";
  font-family: Feather;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: auto;
}
```

I have tried removing the css files in the `index.html` or even adding new fonts but anything work. I don't know if other styles are crashing with Bootstrap.